# По какому принципу в JavaScript пропускаются HTML-комментарии?

Tags: javascript

Например, вот это

```
<script>
    --> -->
    <!-- <!--
    for (var i = 1; false < !--i;) console.log(i);
    <!-- <!--
    console.log("hello");
    <!-- <!--
</script>
```

браузеру нормально. А это

```
<script>
    for (var i = 1; false <!--i;) console.log(i);
</script>
```

ошибка.

Аналогично получается и для NodeJS. Например, я запускаю NodeJS в интерактивном режиме, и получается для первого кода так:

```
> --> -->
undefined
> <!-- <!--
undefined
> for (var i = 1; false < !--i;) console.log(i);
0
undefined
> <!-- <!--
undefined
> console.log("hello");
hello
undefined
> <!-- <!--
undefined
>
```

А для второго так:

```
> for (var i = 1; false <!--i;) console.log(i);
...
```

Обычно для интерпретаторов в интерактивном режиме это значит, что интерпретатор ожидает ввода с новой строки. Почему?

А вот работает:

```
> for (var i = 1; false < !--i;) console.log(i);
0
undefined
>
```

Comment: html !== javascript, почему вы пытаетесь комментарий html вставить в комментарий к javascript? Интересней зачем вы пытаетесь это сделать, а не почему не работает )

Comment: Я попробовал сделать так же в NodeJS. Результат почти такой же (название ошибки другое). А первый пример кода NodeJS съел нормально в режиме консоли по крайней мере.

Comment: причем тут какой-то там html комментарий и то, что парсер не может банально строку разобрать, потому что в первом случае есть знак "меньше" есть отрицание и есть декремент.. а во втором парсер не осиляет знак `<!--` и кидает ошибку........ причём тут какие-то html комментарии — неизветсно

Comment: @Алексей, первый фрагмент кода **работает** и в браузере, **и в node**, а второй - ни там, ни там.

Comment: ты вообще прочитал то, что я написал?

Comment: @Алексей, вроде понял. А может и нет. Но почему парсер осиляет `< !--i` и не осиляет `<!--i` ?

Comment: потому что он не всемогущ

Comment: Лет 12 назад, ответ на вопрос был бы очевиден...

Comment: !--i, это значит отнять от i единицу, и преобразовать в обратный bool тип (если был 0-false станет true и все что не 0 станут false) Поэтому код и работает. А если вы слитно пишете, такого синтаксиса не существует

Comment: Совсем же недавно было первое апреля с подобной проблемой)

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось очень просто. Для обратной совместимости последовательность `<!--` в любом месте эквивалентна началу однострочного комментария `//`. Последовательность `-->` в начале строки, перед которой могут быть пробельные символы или многострочный комментарий `/* ... */`, также эквивалентна началу однострочного комментария.